# Is there a way to use a variable to reference a different variable in c++?

Tags: c++, variables

I'm trying to program a text based adventure game using C++, and part of the game includes a store with random items that appear. I'm new to c++, so please excuse me if my technique is amateurish, but what I'm doing is running a `rand` variable to determine with an `if/else if` chain what each item will be.

```
if (restock == 0)
    {
        srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
        store_item_1_variable = rand() % 99;
        store_item_1_variable = store_item_1_variable + 1;
        if (10 >= store_item_1_variable && store_item_1_variable > 0)
        {
            item_1_name = "The Staff of Beetles";
            item_1_price = 120;
            /**store_item_1 = int StaffOfBeetles;**/

        }
        else if (30 >= store_item_1_variable && store_item_1_variable > 0)
        {
            item_1_name = "Health Potion";
            item_1_price = 15;
            /**store_item_1 = int HealthPotions;**/  
            // I want to increment store_item_1 later
        }
        // else if (etc)
      }
```

later on in the code, when the player is selecting yes to buy the object, I want the following:

```
std::cout << item_1_name;
  while (valid_input == false)
  {
   std::cin >> text_input;
   const char* text_output = text_input.c_str();
   if(strcmp(text_output, "Yes") == 0 ||  strcmp(text_output, "1") == 0)
   {
    gold = gold - item_1_price 
    store_item_1 = store_item_1 + 1; //When you purchase the object, you get +1 of it in you inventory
    valid_input = true;
    }
    // ... yadda yadda yadda
```

what I want from the second code is for it to add `1` to whatever int definition I defined earlier that is asterisked, but I got no idea how. any help?

Comment: You should open your C++ textbook to the chapter that explains how arrays work, and read it. Instead of having ten different variables, or however many there are, you should use a single array, and use an array index to refer to each value in the array.

Comment: Notation like `10 >= store_item_1_variable && store_item_1_variable > 0` doesn't do what you want it to, although it it syntactically valid.

Comment: Yes. Variables that reference other variables are called **pointers**. You should learn how to use them, because they are useful.

Comment: You should also learn arrays. But pointers are what you are asking about.

Comment: How can it be that, in a **C++** question *in 2020*, the comments actually suggest looking at **arrays** and **pointers**? [`<vector>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [references](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference), please...

Comment: @DevSolar references cannot be reassigned

Comment: @DevSolar In my opinion, when teaching a language, it's also better to build up from the ground, than to build down from the top - "here are arrays. Now here are vectors which are like better arrays." I have no teaching qualifications of course.

Comment: @user253751: I stand with [Kate Gregory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk) on this one. Teaching people the C way first, then have them re-think everything to get to idiomatic C++ is ineffective, and counterproductive. There is simply no need for the C way in C++, except for interfacing C or reading really poor "C++" code.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the criticism and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for *pointers*. Here is a really quick introduction:

```
int *selected_item;
// selected_item is a variable which references an int variable.
// (Don't know which one yet!)

// Note: If you do *selected_item here, your program will probably crash,
// but it might also cause different problems, depending on your luck.
// So don't do *selected_item before selected_item refers to an actual variable.

selected_item = &a;
// selected_item references variable a

*selected_item = 5;
// Set the variable which selected_item references to 5.
// a is now 5.

if (something) {
    selected_item = &b;
} else {
    selected_item = &c;
}

// selected_item references variable b or c

*selected_item = *selected_item * 3;
// Set the variable which selected_item references, to whatever was in it before, times 3.
// Either b or c is now 3 times what it was previously.
```

If you put off learning pointers because you thought they were boring, I hope this makes you want to learn them.

Note that you must not use `*selected_item` except when `selected_item` refers to a valid variable which still exists! Otherwise you get "undefined behaviour", which means your program might crash, or it might do weird things and give you a headache from trying to figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a `class` or `struct`

```
#include <string>

struct Item
{
    Item(std::string _name, int _price) : name(_name), price(_price) {}

    std::string name;
    int price;
};
```

Then use it like

```
Item store_item_1;

if (10 >= store_item_1_variable && store_item_1_variable > 0)
{
    store_item_1 = Item("The Staff of Beetles", 120);
}
else if (30 >= store_item_1_variable && store_item_1_variable > 0)
{
    store_item_1 = Item("Health Potion", 15);
}
```

Then if you want to know something about your item

```
std::string name = store_item_1.name;
int price = store_item_1.price;
```

If you want to make several of these, then you can add them to a `std::vector<Item>` and reference them like

```
std::vector<Item> items;
// fill this out
std::string third_name = items[2].name;
```

Or can loop through them

```
for (Item const& item : items)
{
    std::cout << item.name << ' ' << item.price << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Mr Kramer: "10 >= store_item_1_variable && store_item_1_variable > 0" - how could you?!